# Does fastlane nuke deletes push certificates too

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, fastlane, fastlane-match

We lost the match encryption password and have to nuke our existing profiles. I want to be sure running

```
fastlane nuke development
fastlane nuke distribution
fastlane nuke adhoc
```

and thus nuking the old certificates won't delete our APNS push certificates for the same apps.

Or do I have to create new push certificates and send to our backend team too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just had the same question - specifically about Fastlane's `match` command. I couldn't find an answer, so just I created a test app, and the following certificate types:

Development
Distribution
ApplePay
Push Notifications (Development & Production).

When I ran `fastlane match nuke development`, note that I had to provide what type of certificates I wanted to revoke: development or appstore (aka distribution).

Upon nuking both development and appstore (`fastlane match nuke appstore`), only code signing my certificates were revoked. My ApplePay and Push Notification certificates were left untouched.

Beware though, that I did have other certificates that were revoked that were from other app identifiers. It seems as if match nuke does not try to be app identifier specific; but rather, developer account specific.

However, before anything was revoked, I was able to review the ID of each certificate, so I could have checked Keychain access to determine which certificates were about to be revoked.

`+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      Certificates that are going to be revoked      |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Name         | ID         | Type       | Expires    |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+
| iOS          | XXXXXXXXXX | Production | 2020-09-14 |
| Distribution |            |            |            |
| iOS          | XXXXXXXXXX | Production | 2020-09-26 |
| Distribution |            |            |            |
+--------------+------------+------------+------------+`

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks! We had the same experience.

Comment: So can't match handle my push certificates as well?

Comment: From what I have seen, no. But my colleague found that [Fastlane pem](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pem/) does. However, when we found this, we also discovered that Apple Developer [Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list) now supports keys, which don't expire. So if you are looking for an easy way to manage your push certificates, you might consider using a key instead.